# $UserID not working in the <xsl:if>

Tags: sharepoint-designer

```
<xsl:if test="contains(@Uname,$UserID">
```

if there is a match then also always showing the result as false.

Does any one have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this quick fix, It worked for me.

```
<xsl:if test="contains(@Uname,concat('&gt;',$UserID,'&lt;')">
```

Comment: I tried this one as well but no success

Comment: The UserID contained in the field is an integer,try this way also <xsl:if test="contains(@Uname,concat('ID=', $Userid, '&quot;&gt;'))">

Comment: Here the @Uname field is the HTML email Field so does this work for like match with HTML field